# react-native combining two arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to let users select their interest (i.e, food, sports) and then display it on users profile page.

I have two separate views. One is where users select their favorite food and in the next page user could select their favorite sports.

So for example, I want to show `Interest: pizza, hotdog, basketball, surfing` on screen.

The problem I am having is that I can't merge two arrays(food and sports).

```
class UserInterest extends Component {
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this._favoriteFood = this._favoriteFood.bind(this)
       this._favoriteSports = this._favoriteSports.bind(this)

     this.state = {
        food:[],
        sports:[],
        interest:[],   
     }
    } 

     _favoriteFood(foodState){
        const food = foodState
        this.setState({toggle1:food})
        console.log(food)
        console.log(this.state.food)
      }

     _favoriteSports(SportsState){
        const sports = SportsState
        this.setState({toggle2:sports})
        console.log(sports)
        console.log(this.state.sports)
      }

render(){
 const {toggleText1} =this.state
 const {toggleText2} =this.state

return (
<View>
      <FavoriteFood favoriteFood={this._favoriteFood}/>
</View>
       <View>
             <FavoriteSports favoriteSports={this._favoriteSports}/>
       </View>
       <View>
             <Text>{toggleText1}</Text>
       </View>
               <View>
                     <Text>{toggleText2}</Text>
               </Vie>
)
}
```

If I have two arrays `food:[pizza, hotdog]` and `sports:[basketball, surfing]` How could I merge these two arrays and put it in `interest:[]`array?

Also when I `console.log(food)` I get array data, but when I `console.log(this.state.food)` I get an empty array. Shouldn't these be the same? I am confused.

Any advise or comments would be really appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: `intrest: this.state.food.concat(this.state.sports)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the empty array, because your function lost your context, when your call it from another component and `this` contains these components (FavoriteSports, FavoriteFood etc.). So you need to consolidate context of UserInterest component. You can use arrow function for it

```
  _favoriteSports = (SportsState) => {
    const sports = SportsState
    this.setState({toggle2:sports})
    console.log(sports)
    console.log(this.state.sports)
  }
```

For merge arrays you can use es6 spread operator

```
const interest = [...food, ...sports];
```

Comment: so simply change  it to arrow function will output same results? changed it to an arrow function but still `console.log(this.state.sports)` shows undefined.

Comment: This is because the changes will be affected after one clock cycle and the console.log will occur before that

Answer (score 1):

You can use array concat

```
function concatArray(){
  let food=this.state.food;
  let sports=this.state.sports;
  let interest=[];
  interest.concat(food);
  interest.concat(sports);
  this.setState({interest:interest});
}
```

For your second question,

You are passing parameters to the function and changing the state to toggle1 and toggle2. Change the parameters or predefine the state in the constructor.

I also want to clarify this will change the value of the state. But console.log(this.state.sports) will not log the updated value because the changes will be affected after one clock cycle and the console.log will occur before that.

```
_favoriteFood(foodState){
  const food = foodState
  this.setState({food :food})
  console.log(food)
  console.log(this.state.food)
}
```